# Are asp.net detailed error messages disabled on windows azure?

Tags: azure

I have the simplist of web.config files and it works fine locally but on Windows Azure webs it doesnt show detailed errors ?  Do they have them disabled on their services.

You cant get much simpler than this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
        -->
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

But yet I still get the yellow screen of death

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to [config file transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) that happens when you create and deploy package on Azure. Check you web.config file related to build configuration used for Azure deployment (mostly it is 'web.release.config') in your web project. There may be config transformation that are setting `customErrors` to value other than `Off`